# Efficient time series data extract

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a problem in python that I am not sure how to solve efficient. I have a large set of time series data that are read in to a generator. As of now, when I call yield, each data is given back to me one by one. This is all fine when each time series have the same index, where each start on the same date and end on the same date. The problem is when I have a set of time series data that do not have the same start date, but the same end date.

What is the best implementation whereby when I query, it will return a values for that specific date. This way i do not have to worry about start date. Its like point in time.

I use pandas and currently have no clue as to how to implement this efficiently.

Code I use to import csv file by file:

```
def _open_convert_csv_files(self):

    comb_index = None
    for s in self.symbol_list:
        print s
        # Load the CSV file with no header information, indexed on date
        self.symbol_data[s] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
                                  os.path.join(self.csv_dir, '%s.csv' % s),
                                  header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True,
                                  names=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Total Volume']
                              ).sort()


        # Combine the index to pad forward values
        if comb_index is None:
            comb_index = self.symbol_data[s].index
        else:
            comb_index.union(self.symbol_data[s].index)

        # Set the latest symbol_data to None
        self.latest_symbol_data[s] = []

    print ''
    # Reindex the dataframes
    for s in self.symbol_list:
        self.symbol_data[s] = self.symbol_data[s].reindex(index=comb_index, method='pad').iterrows()
```

As you can see, `self.symbol_data[s]` works fine when the time series have same start date, but when they don't, it wont work as during my simulation, I loop through each symbol within the loop to get the data. Another word i need to take in to account the cross-sectional price data for each date of iteration

Love to hear what others are doing to achieve this.

I understand that we can line them all together side by side so their dates match and loop row by row, but then when i have 100k different securities, this is slow in memory. Besides, each csv file is not a single column but multiple columns...

thanks,

---

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Total Volume
19991118    29.69620186 32.63318885 26.10655108 28.71720619 685497
19991119    28.02375093 28.06454241 25.98417662 26.3513 166963
19991122    26.96317229 28.71720619 26.14734257 28.71720619 72092
19991123    27.73821052 28.47245727 26.10655108 26.10655108 65492
19991124    26.18813405 27.37108715 26.10655108 26.80000634 53081
19991126    26.67763189 27.08554675 26.59604891 26.88158932 18955
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv file?  Also, is symbol_list a subset of the file?

Comment: Symbol_list is a list of symbol names, ie ["SPY","GE"]

Comment: I'm not sure how I can post a csv file, it has 6 columns with open high low close prices wih volume and open interest. The index column is simply date. Not intraday data.

Comment: What does the date field look like?  Can you give a sample? (e.g. 20150515 vs 2015-May-05)

Comment: Come to think of it, would a panel representation of my data work? If I have multiple symbols, I have multiple columns representing each symbol. My major axis would be dates and my minor axis would be open high low closes volume data. Not sure if there is a iterrows for panel data in pandas.....

Comment: As a minimalist example, try: import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 5)
web.DataReader(["F", "GM"], 'yahoo', start, end)

The result is read as a panel.

Comment: Assuming you call the returned panel data 'p', then p['Adj Close'] will given you the Adjusted Close of all stocks indexed on date and p.minor_xs('F') will return all data for Ford (OHLCV and Adj Close)

Comment: Panel data can be difficult to work with, so it is generally preferred to add the symbol to the table below. You can then easily slice and reindex the data as you please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75992/discussion-between-alexander-and-user1234440).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this:

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Total Volume
Date                                                                
1999-11-18  29.696202  32.633189  26.106551  28.717206        685497
1999-11-19  28.023751  28.064542  25.984177  26.351300        166963
1999-11-22  26.963172  28.717206  26.147343  28.717206         72092
1999-11-23  27.738211  28.472457  26.106551  26.106551         65492
1999-11-24  26.188134  27.371087  26.106551  26.800006         53081
1999-11-26  26.677632  27.085547  26.596049  26.881589         18955
```

How is this not sufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Say your data looks like this:

```
In [52]: print open('aa1.csv').read()
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Total Volume
1999-11-18,29,32,26,30,10000
1999-11-20,30,33,27,31,9000
1999-11-22,31,34,28,32,8000

In [53]: print open('aa2.csv').read()
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Total Volume
1999-11-18,50,51,49,50,9000
1999-11-19,50,52,48,50,8000
1999-11-21,50,53,47,50,7000
```

You can now load all of the data into an array of `DataFrame`s, adding a `Symbol` column to identify it.

```
In [54]: symbol_list = ['aa1', 'aa2']

In [55]: result = []

In [56]: for symbol in symbol_list:
   ....:         data = pd.read_csv(symbol + '.csv', parse_dates=True)
   ....:         data['Symbol'] = symbol
   ....:         result.append(data)
   ....:
```

These can be concatenated into a *single DataFrame*, which makes it easy to manipulate. We make a pivot table out of it, forward fill the missing values, and re-order the column levels for convenience.

```
In [57]: combined = pd.concat(result).pivot_table(
   ....:     index='Date',
   ....:     columns='Symbol',
   ....:     values=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Total Volume']
   ....: ).ffill().reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1)

In [58]: combined
Out[58]:
Symbol      aa1  aa2  aa1  aa2 aa1 aa2   aa1   aa2          aa1          aa2
           Open Open High High Low Low Close Close Total Volume Total Volume
Date
1999-11-18   29   50   32   51  26  49    30    50        10000         9000
1999-11-19   29   50   32   52  26  48    30    50        10000         8000
1999-11-20   30   50   33   52  27  48    31    50         9000         8000
1999-11-21   30   50   33   53  27  47    31    50         9000         7000
1999-11-22   31   50   34   53  28  47    32    50         8000         7000
```

The `.pivot_table()` operation automatically creates a combined index for you, and you also have the ability to compare a metric across tickers (e.g. `Close` across symbols).

Since this does not have any loops, it should be fairly efficient.

Comment: how to get for example a particular date's closing value for all symbols?

Comment: more precisely, closing prices for 1999-11-18

Comment: `combined.reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1)['Close']` gets you all closing prices. `combined.reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1)['Close'].ix['1999-11-18']` gets you closing prices on 1999-11-18.

Comment: can each row by turned in to a iterator?